# Relation between simple and indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that every simple module is indecomposable but the reverse case isn't true in general. So is there a way or conditions that we can add on the indecomposable modules so that they are a simply module?

Comment: What sort of condition would you be looking for? Being semisimple is an obvious one, but probably not very interesting.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What I want to prove is, consider a finite dimensional complex algebra $A$. Then every indecomposable $A$-module
is also a simple module if and only if we can find some integer $n_i \gt 0$ such that $A \to M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \cdots \oplus M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ (isomorphism).

Comment: You mean that to be an isomorphism? Every indecomposable module being simple is the same as the algebra being semisimple.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Are you saying that Every indecomposable module is simple if and only if the underling algebra is semisimple?

Comment: Well, it depends on your definition, but in this case all the various definitions coincide anyway, so yes.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you give me some advises on how to prove it?